# What is merging 2 classes into 1 class where one class is a subclass of the other called?

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, refactoring, subclass

I have:

- an abstract class A
- an abstract class B that extends A
- no other classes that extends A except B
- other class(es) that extend B

To reduce the number of classes, I want A and B to be merged into one class, and let the other class(es) extend from the new merged class.

What is the name of this refactoring?

P.S. In my implementation it is in Java, can this refactoring be done automatically in IntelliJ?

Comment: Why would you want that? You mean there will never-ever be another class to extend A, that will be supposed to do things differently compared to B? First, remember why you created two classes in the first place, then start thinking whether or not this is a good idea.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes I understand what you mean. What I am currently doing is cleaning up old code written by obsolete people, and now I'm quite sure that A will never be extended except by B.

Comment: What is the name of this refactoring? That is its name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IntelliJ's Inline Superclass performs the merging of a superclass to subclass.

[Inline Superclass](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/inline.html)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think that it would be called "inline"!

Answer (score 3):

You will be inlining class A and intellij supports that. Just right click on the class name and select "refactor" from the pop-up and inlining the class should be an option.